# Javascript to POST to apex rest resource gets Invalid Session ID, but POSTing from third-paty services doesnt, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, rest-api, rest, apexrest, ajax

I'm trying to call into Salesforce via Ajax from another site. I've verified the content of my request is correct using a service to call in using the same JSON and auth token and everything, but when I try it in Javascript it gives me an "INVALID_SESSION_ID" error. Here's the Javascript:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    //caps below are names changed to protect the innocent
    url: "https://INSTANCE.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/RESOURCE", 
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "OAuth MY_TOKEN_HERE", //token is valid.
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    data: newLeadInfoJson, //this is some JSONified data
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(responseData, status, xhr) {
        console.log(responseData);
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {
console.log(error);
    console.log(request);
    }
});
```

As for the resource itself, as I said when I use an online service to do the call into salesforce it goes through splendidly and works like a charm.

My question revolves around this INVALID_SESSION_ID. Clearly it's not invalid, it's the one I'm using right now, and it's the same one I used in that call in from the online service, which worked! What am I missing?

I have verified the session settings allow for other IPs to use the same sessions. I have also checked that my user is API enabled. I know my instance is correct, and I know my resource url is also correct.

EDIT: minor breakthrough, I got it working in visualforce by changing "jsonp" to "json" in the datatype attribute. I still cannot get it to work from my local machine, though. It will do the request but the result won't show up in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether what you are doing is completely secure from CORS perspective, but there is [XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) option that you can use in your jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://bar.other',
data: { whatever:'cool' },
type: 'GET',
beforeSend: function(xhr){
   xhr.withCredentials = true;
});
```

Basically, by default your session cookies will be ignored by default.